# long long variable doesn't show correct answer

Tags: c++, integer-overflow, long-long

its some miscalculation.

I am in trouble with large numbers.
this code works for some smaller inputs(`N`) but for inputs like `100000` it doesn't.

the correct final answer of `result` variable when `N = 100000` must be `4999949998`
but result in this code is `704982702`

```
long long result = 0;
int N;
cin >> N;
.
.          //some changes on result
.
result = result / 2;
long long tmp =( N*(N - 1) ) / 2;
result = tmp - result;
cout << result << endl;
```

but `tmp` is long long too and it doesn't seems an overflow.

but some simple changes made it correct.

```
long long result = 0;
int N;
cin >> N;
.
.          //some changes on result
.
result = result / 2;
long long tmp = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
    tmp += N;
tmp = tmp / 2;
result = tmp - result;
cout << result << endl;
```

I can't find the reason. do you know that?

Answer (score 4):

```
( N*(N - 1) ) / 2
```

I this expression, everything is `int`, therefore the result is calculated in an `int` and overflows while calculating `N*(N - 1)`.

```
( static_cast<long long>(N)*(N - 1) ) / 2
```

Coverting `N`˙to `long long` solves the problem, `long long` mutiplied by an `int` gives `long long` result, as expected, same for division.